# I want to iterate my function over a set of stations and save results for it in a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to iterate my function over a set of stations and save results for it in a dataframe. I already have the function but it saves the the value for the last station in all my rows and doesnt save the other stations results in the dataframe as I would like.[enter image This is the results shown for the first station from the loop which is similar to last stationhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouDl6.png). However after reaching 504 the 505 row value should be for 2nd station but instead I get the last station values again and it repeats till the end. [Now at the last station values are similar to the values saved in place of first station starting at 9073](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtv0B.png)

```
spi_function <- function(precipitation, station_no, spi_period) {
  
  station <- precipitation_chirps %>%
    filter(id == station_no) %>%
    subset(select = -c(id))
  
  station <- as.precintcon.monthly(station)
  
  spi_result <- spi(station, period = spi_period)
  
  print(spi_result)
}

This is my function while this is how I am looping it 

spi_result <- data.frame(year = rep(1981:2022, times = 19, each = 12),
                         month = rep(1:12))

for (j in 1:length(unique(precipitation_chirps$id))) {
  
    spi_result[j,1:3] <- spi_function(precipitation_chirps, j, 1)
  
}
```

Comment: If you provide some reproducible data you will have better lucking finding help. There are a couple of things that could be happening here but it isn't possible to figure out without seeing your data. Don't just post a picture of the input data either, either use `dput(precipitation_chirps)` or create some data with code similar to how you made `spi_result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading your code well, the following is probably right. Instead of iterating by unique `id`, it splits the data by `id` and applies the function to each sub-df. Then puts all results together.

```
spi_function <- function(precipitation, spi_period) {
  station <- as.precintcon.monthly(precipitation)
  spi(station, period = spi_period)
}

spi_id_list <- split(precipitation_chirps, precipitation_chirps$id)
spi_results <- lapply(spi_id_list, spi_function, spi_period = 1)
spi_results <- do.call(rbind, spi_results)
spi_results
```

Comment: Thanks this one worked with a little modification of my own. I had a problem finding this split function, now it will help a lot. Thanks again